# How can we unlock a 7z archive (w/ password) without extracting it?

Tags: compression, zip, 7-zip, archiving

The question in the title. I am aware;

```py
7z x blah.7z -p'mysecretpassword'
```

exists, but I wish to only **unlock** the archive - allowing my Python script to access it. Not extract it.

The reason I can't extract is due to disk size limitations [kaggle](https://kaggle.com). however, certain data loaders I found work with compressed archives fairly well.

Comment: If the only access needed is to see filenames, without extracting file, 7z format allows saving file encrypted, but *with unencrypted filenames*. Otherwise, what can Python do *without* extracting the file?

Comment: Python *will* extract the archive - just in a lazy manner directly to memory https://github.com/webdataset/webdataset. And no, access is required to the data